# where is the reference for msbuild extensibility keywords?

Tags: msbuild, metadata, keyword

I'm working with an msbuild file and I see things like %(copylocal) and @(intermediateassembly).

I know some of them can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx but is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can create your own properties (referenced with `$`) and items (referenced with `@`) with any metadata (referenced with `%`) you like. Take a look at this link and all related to her if you want to know more about main concepts of **MSBuild**: [MSBuild Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171451%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: why would you post a link I posted in my question?